# Verification if the word is correct after send a form

Tags: php

I create this function to include inside a form. It write a name and a number.

My question, I have this element `Dexter_6` . In the verification, How to verify the word is correct with the same element.

Tk
    public static function CreateAntiSpamText() {

```
  $randomChoice  = function($array) {return $array[array_rand($array)];};

  $names = ['Dexter', 'Esther', 'David', 'Richard', 'Rachel', 'Belinda'];
  $number = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

  $random_name = $randomChoice($names);
  $random_number = $randomChoice($number);
  $_SESSION['name'] = $names . '_' . $random_number ;

  return $random_name . '_' . $random_number;
}
```

Comment: why not use googles reCaptacha? https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html. Doing this means it won't be easily fooled. "Roll your own" captchas/anti spam tend to be rather easy to "beat"

Comment: I wnat just to create something like this; It for my learning

Comment: store the result of your CreateAntiSpamText in a session on posting of the form check the session vs the unput.